# image is not clickable in index.html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to make image clickable in rails view page.I tried in index.html.erb file, still it is not coming.

Below is the code I written.

```
<tbody>
    <% @messages.each do |t| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= t.from %></td>

      <td><%= t.subject %></td>
      <td id ="message"><%= image_tag("note.gif")%></td>
    <script type="javascript">
   jQuery("#message").click(function() { jQuery("#message").html("<%=t.message%>") });
</script>
      <td><%=t.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")%></td>

      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', t, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<tbody>
    <% @messages.each do |t| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= t.from %></td>

          <td><%= t.subject %></td>
          <td><%= link_to image_tag("note.gif"), path_to_desired_page %></td>
          <td><%= t.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></td>

          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', t, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Replace `path_to_desired_page` with whatever you want to link the image to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want after clicking image it shows t.message which is already present in @message.